# Reactjs API call for large data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having a problem in loading data of about 26000 data with paging 100 per page using `async`, but the problem is it requests about 200 times. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you include the problem code?